# is the execution of the same function twice worse than associating the result to a variable?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, caml-light

I was told that this first piece of code is, in terms of performance, worse than the second.

But, I honestly cannot figure out how they can be different, if in the end the same calls are made.
Am I missing something?

First example with explicit calls:

```
#let rec max l =
match l with
x::[]->x
| x::xs -> if(x > max xs) 
     then x else max xs;;
```

Second example with variable usage:

```
#let rec max l =
match l with
x::[]->x
| x::xs -> let m = max xs
in
if (x>m) then x else m;;
```

Comment: Why are people downvoting?  Sure, it may be a foolish error--*once you see it*--and someone who understood the code would see it, but OP couldn't see it.  Ignorance isn't a reason for downvotes; not doing your homework is.  But it's not like OP failed to look, or didn't clearly explain what the question was, or failed to show relevant work.  Afaics, OP did the homework but just didn't have the requisite insight, however small it might be.  There might be a reason not to upvote, but not for downvoting.  Discussion after the current answer shows the misunderstanding was deeper.

Comment: @Mars many probably find these questions lame or too newbie-ish to be here, and decide to down-vote... and they have every right to.

Comment: Thanks @user9193072.  That's what I wondered.  I personally disagree with that policy, but there are nuances.  Newbies who make a sincere attempt to figure it out, and show that they did, should be welcome.  I agree that there are some questions for which anybody, no matter how new, should take an additional 20 seconds and see the answer, or actually learn the minimal basics of the language before asking anything.  Those haven't yet made a sincere attempt to figure it out.  This doesn't seem like that kind of case.  Reasonable people can disagree about this, I guess.  Unless I am unreasonable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is that the ocaml compiler does not know that `max xs` and `max xs` are the same thing, so your first example is equivalent to something like:

```
let rec max l =
  match l with
   | x::[]-> x
   | x::xs ->
     let m1 = max xs in (* first call *)
     if (x > m1) then
       x
     else
       let m2 = max xs in
       m2 (* second call *)
;;
```

Making only one call is a valid optimization, but is not correct in the general cases. For example:

```
let f () =
  print_endline "hello";
  print_endline "hello";
  3
```

is not equivalent to:

```
let g () =
  let x = print_endline "hello" in
  x;
  x;
  3
```

Comment: What exactly contains or is associated to  m ?

Comment: `m` is the result of the evaluation of `max xs`, it's not an abbreviation.

Comment: ok... but in a more tangible way, what's being evaluated with `if (x>m)`?

Comment: also, isnt `max xs` changing at each 'cycle'?

Comment: Each time you compute `max xs`  *with the same `xs`*, you get the same result.

Comment: @coredump isn't at each recursion behind executed `max` on a list xs with is deprived of the first element?

Comment: Yes, knowing the maximum value contained in list `xs` and an element `x`, `max` computes the maximum value contained in list `x::xs`. But what you are doing is calling `(max xs)` twice at the same level of recursion. Is `xs` different at both locations where you call `max xs`? No, it is the same list. Hence, `max xs` will give the same result. Only after you know this recursive result you determine which value to return (either x or that value, whichever is greatest).

Comment: @coredump Oh yes, now I see. Being used to the imperative paradigm is complicating a bit adapting to functional programming. Bahut dhanyavaad for the explanation, my friend.